# I want to upload a file in server by using web services in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have developed an application which is uploading a file in my system.Now i want to upload in another system or server. I have given the path of another system but iam getting forbidden 403 error. how to resolve that error.
Any suggestions plz.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the filesystem in a server using asp.net, make sure that the destination directory got the ASP.Net account permissions (give read, write permission to the ASP.Net account on the specific dir)..

Comment: its not abt source code.. go to the directory where u can store the files in server, and add the ASP.Net account to the directory with read & write permission.. and see if it works...